# Create a location map using a variety of photos

Tags: image, gps, photo, image-manipulation

I was asked to form a team which must be thinking \ create a software to create a map of a city (or other), starting from satellite photos (I assume with tags gps).

We decided to create a web app, but we do not know where to start. 
We thought about using jQuery for photo manipulation, but we have no idea which technique we should use the provided.

We need to find the edge of the photo and make a comparison with the other? 
We can take advantage of GPS tags? In what way?

This project will be open source, or so we were told.

Are any of you aware of any software / frameworks / languages​​, etc.. that can help us in our aim?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thank you very much

Comment: How are the GPS tags, aka coordinates provided? Do they come with an extra file? Or do you have to read them as EXIF (Metadata from the image)?

Comment: Unfortunately, we were not given many details, but I think they are to be read from EXIF​​.

Answer (score 0):

I think, a good start is to get familiar with the concept of maps server. Checkout the [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS). This [slide about maps](http://www.slideshare.net/kdelchev/maps-29138951) might also give you a quick intro.

If you need to read the coordinates and image dimensions from the EXIF data, then there are several tools available, depending on you prefered language.

I would approach the problem by setting up a maps server (like [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome)), importing the images and writing a browser based client.